# How do I solve this system of differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, matlab

I have to solve the following system of differential equations

$$
\begin{align}\dot x &= 2000 - 3xy -2x\\
\dot y &= 3xy - 6y\\
\dot z &= 4y - 2z\end{align}
$$

1. Which steps are required to solve it? The only method I know (so far) is separation of variables, which I (probably) can't use.
2. How do I solve it with Matlab?

Comment: Is it an independent variable, say time etc., that $x,y,z$ are differentiated with respect to? Also you can use Simulink to solve it numerically.

Comment: yes... all variables are with respect to time :)

Comment: It's a nonlinear system, so don't expect a nice closed form solution that you can find by hand. A similar example, whose solutions have extremely complex behaviour, is the Lorentz system: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_attractor.

Answer (score 1):

I got one set of solution as

$$
\begin{align*}
x(t) &= \frac{4(k+1)}{3k}\\
y(t) &= \frac{2(749k-1)}{3(k+1)}\\
z(t) &= e^{-2t}+\frac{4(749k-1)}{3(k+1)}
\end{align*}
$$

where $k$ is a constant

First solve $\dot z = 4y - 2z$

Comment: I don't think that's right unless $k=2$ or $k=1/749$.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions with $x$ and $y$ constant are $x=1000, y=0, z = C e^{-2t}$ and $x=2, y=998/3, z = 1996/3 + C e^{-2t}$.  You won't find closed-form solutions other than those, but you can get qualitative information from a phase-plane analysis in the $x,y$ variables.